# Fill NaN based on MultiIndex Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Data Frame that I would like to fill in some NaN values of.

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = [('a', 1990),('a', 1994),('a',1996),('b',1992),('b',1997),('c',2001)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names = ['Type', 'Year'])
vals = ['NaN','NaN','SomeName','NaN','SomeOtherName','SomeThirdName']
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=index)

print(df)

                       0
Type Year               
a    1990            NaN
     1994            NaN
     1996       SomeName
b    1992            NaN
     1997  SomeOtherName
c    2001  SomeThirdName
```

The output that I would like is:

```
Type Year               
a    1990       SomeName
     1994       SomeName
     1996       SomeName
b    1992  SomeOtherName
     1997  SomeOtherName
c    2001  SomeThirdName
```

This needs to be done on a much larger DataFrame (millions of rows) where each 'Type' can have between 1-5 unique 'Years' and the name value is only present for the most recent year.  I'm trying to avoid iterating over rows for performance purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your data frame by index in descending order and then `ffill` it:

```
import pandas as pd
df.sort_index(level = [0,1], ascending = False).ffill()

#                           0
# Type  Year    
#    c  2001    SomeThirdName
#    b  1997    SomeOtherName
#       1992    SomeOtherName
#    a  1996    SomeName
#       1994    SomeName
#       1990    SomeName
```

Note: The example data doesn't really contain `np.nan` values but string `NaN`, so in order for `ffill` to work you need to replace the `NaN` string as `np.nan`:

```
import numpy as np
df[0] = np.where(df[0] == "NaN", np.nan, df[0])
```

Or as @ayhan suggested, after replacing the String "NaN" with `np.nan` use `df.bfill()`.

Comment: Or directly `.bfill()`? :)

Comment: @ayhan Exactly the one needed here.